# Better way to un-define a set of defines based on version numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

In a header I have something like:

```
#define OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION_MAJOR 4
#define OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION_MINOR 0

#define OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION ( OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION_MAJOR * 10 \
                              + OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION_MINOR * 1 )
```

And then a lot of checks like:

```
#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 44
    #ifdef GL_VERSION_4_4
        #undef GL_VERSION_4_4
    #endif
#endif

#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 43
    #ifdef GL_VERSION_4_3
        #undef GL_VERSION_4_3
    #endif
#endif

#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 42
    #ifdef GL_VERSION_4_2
        #undef GL_VERSION_4_2
    #endif
#endif

#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 41
    #ifdef GL_VERSION_4_1
        #undef GL_VERSION_4_1
    #endif
#endif
```

...

Is there any way I could avoid repeating these checks for every version-number?

Answer (score 3):

While it's somewhat uncertain whether you'll like it (some compilers warn about doing so) it's entirely permissible to `#undef` a value that wasn't defined to start with, so you can consolidate these down to something like:

```
#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 44
    #undef GL_VERSION_4_4
#endif

#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 43
    #undef GL_VERSION_4_3
#endif

#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 42
    #undef GL_VERSION_4_2
#endif

#if OPENGL_TARGET_VERSION < 41
    #undef GL_VERSION_4_1
#endif
```

While this does (or at least sort of might) answer the question you asked, from a code review standpoint, I'd probably prefer the code as it's written in the question. It's longer, but:

1. it's almost certainly hidden in a header almost nobody really reads through very often
2. it's simple repetitions of a simple pattern, so reading it isn't much work,
3. eliminating the `#ifdef` *will* give warnings with some compilers

   While I think that's a pretty stupid warning, eliminating the warning is still worth more than reducing the line count.

Comment: Pretty certain some compilers will barf (ie fail) if you try and undef and macro that is not already defined. Not all but there are some. Best to leave it the long winded way for portability.

Comment: @LokiAstari: They can issue a warning if they want--but if they fail to compile the code, that's a clear-cut compiler bug.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I already added the ifdef checks.